# Build SSIS T-SQL expression with IN clause

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssis, expression

Wonder if anyone can help here. I am trying build a dynamic T-SQL to construct something like this below on a data flow task

```
Select * 
from Table A 
where RecordID NOT IN (@objectvariable)
```

I have created a variable called `@objectvariable` as object to hold a list of `RecordID` and set up a SQL task and with result set option to "full result set" and mapped the result set variable.

The SQL task executes successfully and populates the list.

When I use this variable in a data flow task and construct the T-SQL script I get an error

> The data type of variable "User::ProcessedData" is not supported in an expression.
>   Reading the variable "User::ProcessedData" failed with error code 0xC00470D0.

In a nutshell I want to build T-SQL like

```
Select * 
from Table A 
where RecordID NOT IN (100,102,103)
```

in a dataflow ado source task by using a variable to bring the 'IN' values. Is this possible?

Many thanks

Comment: There's no straight forward way of doing this. Read this thread: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1067780-147-1.aspx

Comment: Store those values in a table and use that.  You can drop/truncate the table afterwords, if that's a concern.

Comment: Is the data in @objectvariable coming from a database? If so, what version / vendor?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution is to produce the comma separated string value within your original data source (using one of the many value concatenation methods for each RDBMS vendor you can find on StackOverflow and other sites). Then just stick that into a String variable and build your dynamic query.

Having said that, you can also use a Script Task to convert your Recordset object into a comma-separated string. Here's a C# script that does that for you (see below code for usage notes):

```
#region Namespaces
using System;
using System.Data;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Linq;

#endregion

namespace ST_75a10d235ce24be89bab80890dca9be9
{
    /// <summary>
    /// ScriptMain is the entry point class of the script.  Do not change the name, attributes,
    /// or parent of this class.
    /// </summary>
    [Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.SSISScriptTaskEntryPointAttribute]
    public partial class ScriptMain : Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTARTScriptObjectModelBase
    {
        public void Main()
        {

            OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt, Dts.Variables["User::ContractSet"].Value);
            Dts.Variables["User::ContractValues"].Value = String.Join(",", dt.AsEnumerable().Select(r => r.Field<string>("contract")).ToArray());

            Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
        }

        #region ScriptResults declaration
        /// <summary>
        /// This enum provides a convenient shorthand within the scope of this class for setting the
        /// result of the script.
        /// 
        /// This code was generated automatically.
        /// </summary>
        enum ScriptResults
        {
            Success = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Success,
            Failure = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Failure
        };
        #endregion

    }
}
```

- Create two variables, one Object (User::ContractSet in the example) and one String (User::ContractValues) in your package.
- Set the User::ContractSet as a ReadVariable and User::ContractValues as a ReadWriteVariable on your Script Task.
- Note you'll have to set the fieldname you're concatenating from your Recordset in the LINQ select query (it's "contract" in the example.)
- This script requires references to the System.Data.DataSetExtensions and System.Linq assemblies.

Place this task after your data flow populating User::ContractSet and then User::ContractValues will have a comma-separated list you can use to build a dynamic query.